# hex colors, possible combinations

Tags: html, css, colors, hex

so I have used hex colors in html, and css in these ways: `#000000` and `#000` , as well as with the alpha variables `#00000000`

that gives us hex versions that are both 6 characters, 3 characters, and 8 characters.

it stands to reason that the 3 character version could have an alpha variable too, making a 5 character version that would look like `#00000`. Does this exist and is it recognized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the spec

> Unlike RGB values, there is no hexadecimal notation for an RGBA value.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/

Comment: that is INTERESTING. I picked up using `#aarrggbb` from a colleague and it works in places

Comment: it might work, but the spec says it's not supposed to be implemented that way.  Then again, browsers don't always follow the spec for their implementations.  To be safe, you should just use `rgba()`

Comment: Boy, how I wish there was a #rrggbbaa (or a in front, I don't care). The rgba(r, g, b, a) syntax is needlessly verbose. Marat's syntax would be better than the function as well.

Answer (score 2):

If it did exist, it would be a four-character long one - why should the alpha channel get eight bits when the others only get four?

I don't believe it is supported. Mind you, the only place I've seen that recognises `#aarrggbb` is IE's filter properties...

Answer (score 1):

I've always had to use rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0) to leverage the alpha channel. Never seen it successfully used in a #ffffffff syntax.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question from an html/css perspective - as everyone else pointed out, this is not supported in CSS3.

That said, since this question is tagged as "color" and "hex" as well, I did want to point out that Android currently supports an #AARRGGBB format for use in their layout xml attributes and for parsing into a Color object.  I have used it there before with great success.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor

This documentation shows that #RRGGBB and #AARRGGBB are the only supported hex representations.  However, I remember using #RGB at some point in the past, so I assume that #ARGB would work as well (as opposed to #AARGB like you originally posited).

If you ever do try this out on Android, def let me know the results!

Answer (score 0):

No. Also, it would not be a five digit hex code but a four digit hex code like `#0000` **if** it would exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently impossible. There was a related [discussion](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Sep/0048.html) on www-style@w3.org mailing list where I've proposed following convenient syntax:

- `#cad8d9.0` — zero opacity;
- `#cad8d9.27` — 27% opacity;
- `#cad8d9.275` — 27.5% opacity;
- `#cad8d9` — 100% opacity (no need for opacity component at all, using just regular hex value).

But that has been rejected (as many of third-party ideas, unfortunately).